# why time delay is require for display in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm using goahed web server in my embedded device.
My Problem description as per below.

case 1:

```
hideSomeElements();
ShowSomeElements();
ajaxRequestToWebServer();
```

result: ShowSomeElement part is executing but element with .GIF image is not displaying in chrome and I.E. but display in Fire-fox.

case 2:

```
  hideSomeElements();
  ShowSomeElements();
 //ajaxRequestToWebServer(); make comment
```

result:  ShowSomeElement part is executing and element with .GIF image is displaying normally in all browser(chrome + I.E. +Fire-fox).

case 3:

```
hideSomeElements();
ShowSomeElements();
setTimeOut(ajaxRequestToWebServer, 420);
```

result:  ShowSomeElement part is executing and element with .GIF image is displaying normally in All Browser(chrome + I.E. + Fire-fox).

---

Now i wan't to understand that why this element div is display with time delay or with out ajaxRequestToWebServer in chrome browser.

---

My Html and .Js Architecture is as per below

```
<html>
<!-- 
(1) Whole page div placed Here 
(2) Include Js and other css file from here
(3) $(document).ready(function()
    { 
       initJsFile();
    }
-->
</html>
```

Js File Architecture

```
(1) All Functionality define above
(2) initJsFile(); //In Last
```

---

As per html and .js file it's clear that here i load all element before js file init than why it's require extra time delay of 420 ms before ajax Request.

Comment: Please write a snippet demonstrating your problem so that we don't have to guess what your bug is. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should put your HTML in the question also

Comment: hi techie_28 i put here html and js page architecture here please go through it.